# Menu mobile, problema com delegação de evento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou criando um menu desktop/mobile que será replicado algumas vezes na pagina, no entanto meu código apresenta um bug que ao clicar em abrir um acaba abrindo todos. Segue o codigo

```
<div class="nav-section">
    <div class="menu-button-section">Mobile Menu</div>

    <ul class="menu-section active-menu">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
```

A classe **"active-menu"** possui apenas um **visibility:hidden;** para abrir e fechar o menu, o script feito consegue delegar e identificar em qual botão está clicando, no entanto não identifica qual o menu que está trocando a classe tendo em vista que esse html vai ser replicado algumas vezes

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-button-section', function () {
 if( $('.menu-section').hasClass('active-menu')){
    $('.menu-section').removeClass('active-menu');
  } else {
     $('.menu-section').addClass('active-menu');
  }   });
```

O bug acontece nessa linha, aonde ja tentei de algumas formas transformar esse ".menu-section" em um target delegado, mas sem sucesso

```
$('.menu-section').removeClass('active-menu');
```

Comment: Conhece o objeto `this` do Javascript?

Comment: foi, conseguir resolver ontem, só não publiquei, vou postar a resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir resolver o problema, mudando a hierarquia do html, deixando o botão dentro do ul e utilizando o método this

O script ficou assim :

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-button', function () {
 if( $(this).children('.menu').hasClass('active-menu')){
     $(this).children('.menu').removeClass('active-menu');
   } else {
     $(this).children('.menu').addClass('active-menu');
   }  });
```

Comment: Leia também sobre a função [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: Na verdade confundi o metodo com slidetoggle rsrsrs

Comment: Toggle class buga meu layout na hora de voltar a versão desktop

Comment: Então tem mais coisa errada no seu layout/script.